# ActiveRecord::SessionStore - how to share the session for Single Sign On (SSO)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have the requirement for doing a "Single Sign On" between Rails and Java applications. Both the applications are sharing the same database. Currently Rails is making use of default - Cookie based store and we are planning to switch it to Active Record session store, so that it will maintain the sessions in the database and which can be further leveraged for providing the seamless access into these 2 applications using SSO - by identifying the active session of the user.

So is there a way we could find the active session for a user from sessions table ? Would there be a chance of having multiple active sessions for a single user in sessions table ? If yes, we should be referring to most recent entry right ? Any additional things we should consider for doing SSO between these application ? Please note, both are sharing the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing db between multiple applications is not implementation of SSO.The standard sso implementation need a CAS（Central Authentication Service),which provide authentication service for other applications.All users access to other applications need rediect to CAS for authentication.[image: The theory of SSO]

If you want to share session info by sharing db, [this gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) maybe help.Furthermore, it's bad idea to sharing db between multiple applications, it make application hard to maintain.

Comment: You're right, and I know sharing db between multiple applications is not implementation of SSO, and it is not as per the standard practice. But we are in situation that, both the applications are using same database and we need to provide seamless access to both application, without doing login multiple times. So was thinking if we could achieve this using Active Record session store.